# Mongo DB maxScan - Unrecognized field

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm using Mongo v4.2, and I'm trying to limit the documents scanned using maxScan. I've tried "limit" but I believe that pulls all matching documents then slices the array, I actually want to stop mongo from scanning past the first 5 docs.
Here is the error I get:

```
db.movies.find({title: 'Godfather'}).maxScan(5)
Error: error: {
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1598049657, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Failed to parse: { find: \"content_movies\", filter: { title: \"Godfather\" }, maxScan: 5.0, lsid: { id: UUID(\"de0fad49-6cd1-425f-896a-77aa7229e4f0\") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1598049547, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 98F9B39F0F6B9E8088947EF37506EA8B17F8AFAA), keyId: 6838904097895088131 } }, $db: \"PRODUCTION\" }. Unrecognized field 'maxScan'.",
    "code" : 9,
    "codeName" : "FailedToParse",
    "$clusterTime" : {
            "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1598049657, 1),
            "signature" : {
                    "hash" : BinData(0,"/oI+65SAR7fEGyp9yilR+PFG3KQ="),
                    "keyId" : NumberLong("6838904097895088131")
            }
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Mongo removed the maxScan option in 4.2.  This link - https://www.bookstack.cn/read/mongodb-4.2-manual/4c4e41aeabbd3735.md#Remove%20maxScan - suggests to use maxTimeMS option instead.  However, that option doesn't fit your use case.

Comment: I seriously doubt Mongo would pull all the documents before slicing, barring the need to do so because another operation in the query like sort.  Imagine an extremely large collection and a query that matches most of the documents.  It would be foolish and detrimental for Mongo to retrieve and cache all matches when the user only wants the first five.

Answer (score 0):

maxScan is [removed in 4.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-maxscan).

> MongoDB removes the deprecated option maxScan for the find command and the mongo shell helper cursor.maxScan(). Use either the maxTimeMS option for the find command or the helper cursor.maxTimeMS() instead.

> I actually want to stop mongo from scanning past the first 5 docs

Use [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) for this.